# Finding orthonormal basis quickly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: The Question]
I know that the matrix has rank ≤ 3 because the first column is a multiple of the second column. How do we find out that the rank is actually 2. And then, how do we find the orthonormal basis is (E).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to orthonormality and common sense the real choice here is between (B) and (E). We should check that E is enough.

If we subtract 4th column from the 3rd, we get $(5,-5,10) = 2(1,-1,2)$, which is the first column, so that ensures you that rank is 2 and the answer is (E).

Answer (score 0):

You already figured out that the rank is $\leq 3$, which is also obvious from the number of rows of the matrix.
From the given options you can immediately rule out A and C, since the third entry is zero in these options and your matrix has non-zero entries in the last row.
D is not orthonormal, since the first vector has length $\sqrt 6$.
So you are left with options B and E.
Check the determinant of your matrix without the second column. If it is zero, the only remaining option is E.

By the way E is the result of the so called [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) applied to the columns of your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Gram-Schmidt you end up dividing the columns by the magnitude of the vectors. So you can tell it is $E$ without doing anything but I'm just going to do this.

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 & -3 \\ -1 & 1 & -3 & 2\\ 2 & -2 & 5 & -5  \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$

looking at the Gram Schmidt procedure 
[image]

$$ v_{1} = a_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \tag{2} $$

$$ r_{11} = \| v_{1}\| = \sqrt{1 + 1 + 4} = \sqrt{6} \tag{3} $$

you see the $\sqrt{6}$ they're dividing by

$$ q_{1} = \frac{v_{1}}{r_{11}} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&   \frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}\end{bmatrix} \tag{4}$$

now you can stop..you've eliminated everything else.